# Want to remove any HTML tags

Tags: javascript, regex

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Strip HTML from Text JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/822452/strip-html-from-text-javascript)

Here's a string

```
var s = "This is <strong>something</strong>."
```

And I want to remove any HTML tags from this string.

It doesn't matter if your answer is not about regex. Thanks.

Comment: Thou shall not regex HTML. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
s.replace(/<[^>]*?>/g, '');
```

## [JsFiddle DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/WMsYJ/)

Comment: That is not the best way.  Better hope you don't have any math on your page `n<1; or 1+1>0` and you better hope your HTML doesn't span multiple lines `<input type="text"\n   class="..."\n   id="..."\n /><div>...</div>`  innerpage white-space can be a formatting nightmare, thus I often span my HTML elements across multiple lines

Comment: @vol7ron - `n<1` isn't actually legal HTML (it should be `n&lt;1`) though many browsers will tolerate it.

Answer (score 1):

following jQuery sample will help you

```
function getString(html)
{
   return  $("<DIV>").html(html).text();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[Strip HTML from Text JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/822452/strip-html-from-text-javascript)

try this one.to be useful this you have to put your string in html and body tags.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `innerText` property of DOM elements (or `textContent` for Firefox):

```
var s = 'This is <strong>something</strong>.',
    div = document.createElement('div');
div.innerHTML = s;
s = div.innerText || div.textContent;
```